# How to handle nullreferenceexception without skipping legitimate loops?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have the following code:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{

    string itemId = item.ID.ToString();
    string contentType = item.ContentType.ToString();
    string displayName = item.DisplayName;
    string name = item.Name;

    // todo: Title not always retreiving? Likely due to folders, needs more handling
    //string title = item["Title"].ToString() ?? null;
    string title = "";

    string url = item.Url;
    string author = item["Created By"].ToString();

    // todo: Checked out files catering
    const string checkedOutBy = "";

    DateTime lastModified = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Modified"]);
    string lastModifiedBy = item["Modified By"].ToString();
    DateTime created = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]);


    query.RecordItems(itemId, contentType,
                        displayName, name,
                        title, url, author,
                        checkedOutBy,
                        lastModified,
                        lastModifiedBy,
                        created,
                        author);
}
```

The issue I have is that on some iterations of the loop Title or ContentType will throw a Nullreferenceexception, but not on all of them. I believe I've catered for this with the following, but I'm not sure - is there a better way?

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
    try
    {
        string itemId = item.ID.ToString();
        string contentType = item.ContentType.ToString();
        string displayName = item.DisplayName;
        string name = item.Name;

        // todo: Title not always retreiving? Likely due to folders, needs more handling
        //string title = item["Title"].ToString() ?? null;
        string title = "";

        string url = item.Url;
        string author = item["Created By"].ToString();

        // todo: Checked out files catering
        const string checkedOutBy = "";

        DateTime lastModified = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Modified"]);
        string lastModifiedBy = item["Modified By"].ToString();
        DateTime created = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]);


        query.RecordItems(itemId, contentType,
                            displayName, name,
                            title, url, author,
                            checkedOutBy,
                            lastModified,
                            lastModifiedBy,
                            created,
                            author);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("[{0}] Filed moving on file {1} as not all content was present", item.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949(v=office.12).aspx Please, consder some SharePoint best practices. For example `Do not enumerate entire SPList.Items collections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter the items and loop them as below

```
list = list.Items.Where(i=> i.ContentType !=null && i["Title"] !=null).ToList();
```

if you don't need to do all above validations and filters, you better move to `for loop`

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
       SPListItem item = list.Items[i];
       // your code 
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("[{0}] Filed moving on file {1} as not all content was present", item.Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: `SPListItem item = list.Items[i];` no. You don't do it in SharePoint because it won't cache `list.Items` but will get the list from server every time

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly OP not given details about `list`. It may be Cached List already, Do You think it is the root course of this exception?

Comment: Obviously it is not the source of exception, but it is highly unrecommended way to work with `SPList.Items`. `list` is `SPList` because it can be nothing else in this context.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Please answer to this question and provide your solution. definitely it will help someone. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I think @Tigran answer is right and i already added link to SharePoint best practices as comment. There is nothing to add. Your answer is ok, but SharePoint can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: Also Linq query you provided will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I really uderstand the problem here, so why not just ..

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
   ...... 
   if(title == null || item.ContentType == null) 
       continue;


   ....
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: The code in question will throw on `item.ContentType.ToString();` so you should check `item.ContentType` rather than `contentetype`